# FB api - pull number of unread message from page's mailbox

Tags: php, javascript, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

I'm trying to pull the 'unread' messages from our Facebook Page (as opposed to an individual user's page. I'm trying to use FQL to pull the data;

```
SELECT folder_id, viewer_id, name, unread_count, total_count 
FROM mailbox_folder 
WHERE folder_id = '0' and viewer_id = '$pageID'
```

$pageID is the ID of the page.

I have manage_pages permissions on the user's account, and that account is an administrator for the page. Since it is a new feature from facebook to allow messages direct to pages, I am wondering if it's not yet possible to obtain this information via FQL.

I get an error message which says;

> (#606) You can only fetch messages for one user

When I look up for permissions (manage pages, publish stream and read_mailbox) for the page, as opposed to the user, the following is returned;

```
 "manage_pages": 0,
 "publish_stream": 1,
 "read_mailbox": 0
```

I don't know I can request the read_mailbox permission from the page as oppose to the user. Does anyone have any idea how I might achieve the above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this document which shows how to obtain a page access token - https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/pages/

Summary: get `manage_pages` permission from the page admin and obtain the page access token from `/USER_ID/accounts`

Also, here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/page (see 'Mailbox' - shows how to read the mailbox in the Graph API - it should be applicable in FQL too)